# Lottie animation stopped when i tap on different tab bar item

Tags: ios, swift, lottie

Im using Lottie animation in my app and im trying to keep the animation running in the background when i exit the app and open it again (not force close) ..

I was able to do so successfully, but the problem is the animation stops when i select different tab bar item and go back to the tab bar item that has the animation view.

[image: Screenshot]

this is my code.

```
import UIKit
import Lottie
import UserNotifications
import NotificationCenter

class HomeViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var animationView: UIView!
    var animation : AnimationView?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupAnimation()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(applicationEnterInForground), name: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)
    }

    func setupAnimation() {
        animation = AnimationView(name: "cong")
        animation?.frame = self.animationView.bounds
        self.animationView.addSubview(animation!)
        animation?.loopMode = .loop
        animation?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        animation?.play()
    }

    @objc func applicationEnterInForground() {
        if animation != nil {
            if !(self.animation?.isAnimationPlaying)! {self.animation?.play()}}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Better, use `viewWillAppear/viewDidAppear` to start the animation again and remove observing the `willEnterForegroundNotification`.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    if self.animation?.isAnimationPlaying == false {
       self.animation?.play()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 38):

**Swift 5**

There is a property, that can be set & it will restore your Lottie animation:

```
yourAnimationView.backgroundBehavior = .pauseAndRestore
```

By default, this property is set to `.pause`

Comment: This appears to fix the issue. Thanks

Comment: When you are using Lottie, especially for TabBar should it be in one single color, or does support multi-colors?  @Krekin any idea on this. I currently received a Lottie with multiple colors and the tab bar do not support it